# I can’t write code to output data and create a vector

Tags: octave

Using Excel, a file was created and saved as CSV. There are two columns in the file X=1:1:100.,Y=1,1*X^2. In Matlab(octave), you need to create a vector X=1:1:100 and plot the function Y=X^2 and output data from an Excel file to the same graph.

```
         X=1:1:100 

          Y=X.^2 

           plot(X,Y) 

            xlabel X 
            YLabel  Y
            title('My')
              nrows=2; 
            ncolumns=100; 

            data = textscan('mam.csv') 

            data= cell2mat(data); 
            data= transpose(data)
```

why does it only output the graph of the first function and not read the file?

Comment: “Help me write code” is not a question about programming. This is not how this website works. Please read [ask].

Comment: If your question is about Octave, please write explicitly and not Matlab (octave) and remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: Use `fopen` to open the file and generate file ID and then use it with `textscan` with the format of the data.

Comment: Gives an error: cannot open the file for reading

Comment: Can you give the complete exact error message? Does it start with “error: fopen…”. It sounds like either octave doesn’t have read access to the file. Is it in the current working directory?

Comment: @НикДжей , Written: data=textscan( fopen( ‘mam.csv’ , ‘r’), ‘%s’ , “Delimiter “, “ “ , “headerLines” 1); syntax errors

Comment: can you please update the question above with exactly what you are typing and (copy and paste) exactly what output you are seeing?

the code above does not run in octave.  (e.g., function names are case-sensitive.  there is no YLabel function, there is a ylabel one.)

A syntax error will give you an indicator of in which line, and sometimes where in the line you mistyped something.

Comment: I copied and pasted your 'data = ' line from your last comment into my octave cli.  it appears that you are using non-ASCII characters in your text string.  the quotes around you filename are not `'` or `"` which would be valid inputs. You are also missing a comma between "headerlines" and 1.  if i rewrite your line as:
`data = textscan (fopen("mam.csv", "r"), "%s", "Delimeter", " ", "headerlines", 1);` it runs without a syntax error.

Comment: ok, the code has been simplified in the question (maybe an edit reverted? I can't even see that version of code with "headerlines" in the edit history.)  Fixing YLabel -> ylabel, it runs without error assuming there's no issue with mam.csv

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment above, and from the several versions of code posted for your script, it appears you have a number of syntax errors, and may also have been mixing non-ascii characters into your code which Octave won't be able to interpret. The answer below tries to provide some insight into interpreting what messages were likely produced so that similar errors and solutions can be recognized later:

First, function names in Octave are case sensitive.  `YLabel` is not the same as `ylabel`.  Running your code one line at a time, it runs the first few lines and plots the function, then on that line you get:

```
>> YLabel  Y
error: 'YLabel' undefined
```

if you were running this from a script file the error would be:

```
error: 'YLabel' undefined near line 8, column 13
error: called from
    testscript at line 8 column 13
```

This error message is telling you that it doesn't recognize YLabel as a named function, variable, etc., and you should double check spelling, syntax, etc.

Changing that line to `ylabel Y`, the code runs as expected.

Next, the line to read the file:

`data = textscan('mam.csv')`

should correctly read the file assuming there is nothing wrong with `mam.csv` itself.

A previous version of that `textscan` line produced syntax error messages.  It contained both non-standard characters as quotes and was also missing a comma.  The quote character problem is quite common when copying/pasting code from a document or website. E.g., trying to run the following line:

`data = textscan (fopen(‘mam.csv’, ‘r’), ‘%s’, ‘Delimeter’, ‘ ’, ‘headerlines’, 1);`

will produce the following syntax error in Octave:

```
>> data = textscan (fopen(‘mam.csv’, ‘r’), ‘%s’, ‘Delimeter’, ‘ ’, ‘headerlines’ 1);
error: parse error:

  syntax error

>>> data = textscan (fopen(‘mam.csv’, ‘r’), ‘%s’, ‘Delimeter’, ‘ ’, ‘headerlines’ 1);
                           ^
```

Note that Octave is doing it's best to point you to the specific location of the syntax error with a `^` character, here pointing to the first nonstandard character: `‘`.  Replace all of the `‘` and `’` with pairs of `'` or `"`, and the line will then tell you where the next error occurs:

```
>> data = textscan (fopen("mam.csv", "r"), "%s", "Delimeter", " ", "headerlines" 1)
error: parse error:

  syntax error

>>> data = textscan (fopen("mam.csv", "r"), "%s", "Delimeter", " ", "headerlines" 1)
                                                                                  ^
```

Note it's now pointing to the 1 following "headerlines".  it was expecting a comma or other valid argument symbol and was pointing to the location where something is wrong. It can't always tell you what is wrong because it doesn't know your intent, but the error messages do their best to point to the area of concern.